# photoshop rectangle marquee dimensions and info dimensions differ

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selection

I select one element on my psd design. 
Rectangle marquee says smaller size(9px), but after i let my mouse - info panel says element is 15px in width. I'm using photoshop cs6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the marquee's feather set to 1px. Change this to 0px.

[image]